# Python: Is there a way to extract and concatenate several series of text files, dropping the top 3 rows of each file as I go along?

Tags: python

I have a folder containing several series of text files, each containing a single row of residuals from some analysis. Their file names are like this:

```
'residual_x01'
'residual_x02'
...
'residual_y01'
'residual_y02'
...
'residual_z01'
'residual_z02'
```

The contents of the files look like this:

```
1 ### This is the file number in the series
c:\file\location\goes\here
983 1051 0 0 983 1051 ### other identifier
1.1 ### this is where the data I want starts
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
... ## so on for about a million lines.
```

Using Python, I would like to extract the residuals from these files, concatenate to form one long file for each series (i.e. x, y, z), and remove the top three lines of each file as I go, i.e. to form this:

```
1.1 ### data from first file of series 'residual_x01 / _y01 / _z01'
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
...
1.1 ### data from second file of series 'residual_x02 / _y02 / _z02'
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
...
1.1 ### data from third file of series 'residual_x03 / _y03 / _z03'
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
... ... and so on.
```

I am at a loss as to how to to this, can anyone help?

Comment: your question description is very clear, except your own code till now. post it here

Comment: It's not clear what in particular you need help with. E.g. this question might be about how to write and run a Python script at all. Or about how to read from a file, about how to write to a file, about whether you can open several files at once or about how to nest loops. Maybe about how to think about problem-solving. Or maybe something else again. We really need more information about _what problem you are having_ to be able to give effective, focused help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much data, so I made some bogus data. I didn't want to make a bunch of files, so I only made three fake data files, but the code should work for any number of files, and the length of each file can be variable, too.

Let's say you've got the following three text files:

**files/residual_x01.txt**

```
1
c:\file\location\goes\here
983 1051 0 0 983 1051
1.1
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
```

**files/residual_x02.txt**

```
2
c:\file\location\goes\here
983 1051 0 0 983 1051
7.1
8.4
0.3
2.3
0.1
```

**files/residual_y01.txt**

```
1
c:\file\location\goes\here
983 1051 0 0 983 1051
4.2
4.3
1.3
0.2
0.0
```

Code:

```
def get_file_lines(path_to_file):

    from itertools import islice

    number_of_lines_to_skip = 3

    with path_to_file.open("r") as file:

        _ = list(islice(file, number_of_lines_to_skip))
        for line in file:
            yield line.strip()


def get_all_floats(path_to_dir):

    from pathlib import Path

    for path in Path(path_to_dir).glob("residual_*.txt"):
        for line in get_file_lines(path):
            yield float(line)


def main():

    for f in get_all_floats("files/"):
        print(f)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
1.1
3.5
0.8
0.7
1.3
7.1
8.4
0.3
2.3
0.1
4.2
4.3
1.3
0.2
0.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each series, you can create a file containing all the lines from files except the first 3 lines of each using this code:

```
filenames = ['residual_x01', 'residual_x02', ...]
output_file = 'path/to/output/residual_x'
lines_to_skip = 3
with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            lines = infile.readlines()[lines_to_skip:]
            for line in lines:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Change `filenames` list and `output_file` according to your needs. Also you can tweak `lines_to_skip` variable.